# if statements producing incorrect results

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm making a game that produces a 3 pointed star (3PS) and 4 pointed star (4PS). You must make 3PS fall to the right, and 4PS to the left. Im using if statements to check if they have fallen down the correct route but its not working properly. I've created a star class for 3PS and a class 4PS which extends 3PS class. I have a variable that increments every time a star falls below the screen, the 3PS seems to be ok but the 4PS increments the variable for the 4PS and the 3PS. How can I fix this?

Here is my code

```
           if (0 <= starW && starW <= (.5 * dimension[0]) && starH <= 0) {
                    if (star[a] instanceof fourStar) {
                        if (count4Check == false) {
                        count4C++;
                        count4Check = true;
                        starAdded = 0;
                        Log.i("count4C", String.valueOf(count4C));
                   }count4Check = false;
                }
            }
            if (0 <= starW && starW <= (.5 * dimension[0]) && starH <= 0) {
                    if (star[a] instanceof Star) {
                        if (count3Check == false) {
                        count3W++;
                        count3Check = true;
                        starAdded = 0;
                        Log.i("count3W", String.valueOf(count3W));
                   }count3Check = false;
                }
            }
            if ((.5 * dimension[0]) <= starW && starW <= dimension[0] && starH <= 0) {
                    if (star[a] instanceof Star) {
                        if (count3Check == false) {
                        count3C++;
                        count3Check = true;
                        starAdded = 0;
                        Log.i("count3C", String.valueOf(count3C));
                    }count3Check = false;
                }
            }
            if ((.5 * dimension[0]) <= starW && starW <= dimension[0] && starH <= 0) {
                    if (star[a] instanceof fourStar) {
                        if (count4Check == false) {
                        count4W++;
                        count4Check = true;
                        starAdded = 0;
                        Log.i("count4W", String.valueOf(count4W));
                    }count4Check = false;
                }
            }
```

Here is the logcat

```
03-21 20:06:36.620  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 3 star added
03-21 20:06:39.623  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3C﹕ 9
03-21 20:06:39.713  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 4 star added
03-21 20:06:42.276  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count4C﹕ 2
03-21 20:06:42.276  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3W﹕ 5
03-21 20:06:42.356  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 3 star added
03-21 20:06:45.149  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3W﹕ 6
03-21 20:06:45.239  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 4 star added
03-21 20:06:48.592  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count4C﹕ 3
03-21 20:06:48.592  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3W﹕ 7
03-21 20:06:48.692  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 4 star added
03-21 20:06:51.726  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count4C﹕ 4
03-21 20:06:51.726  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3W﹕ 8
03-21 20:06:51.776  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 3 star added
03-21 20:06:54.779  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3C﹕ 10
03-21 20:06:54.859  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 3 star added
03-21 20:07:10.446  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3C﹕ 11
03-21 20:07:10.526  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/MyGLRenderer﹕ 4 star added
03-21 20:07:25.772  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count3C﹕ 12
03-21 20:07:25.772  24716-25725/com.example.james.sata I/count4W﹕ 3
```

Comment: Why not create separate classes for 3PS and 4PS, that'll make it easier to distinguish them. They can both extend star class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

four star is subclass of star so it will also pass that if

```
if (star[a] instanceof Star) {
```

You could for example have code:

```
boolnea isOnLeft = starW <= (.5 * dimension[0]);
boolean isOut = starH <= 0;

if (star[a] instanceof fourStar) {
  if (isOnLeft && isOut) {
  ...
  }
} else { //3ps
  if (!isOnLeft && isOut) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Nevertheless it is not very OO if you check for the actuall class.
You should have Star class with two sublcasses 3PS and 4PS. Then in star class you define abstract method `boolean shouldCount(position)`, in 3PS you implement the shouldCount() to return true if the position is on the right and out of the screen, in 4PS other way around. Then you simply call `shouldCount` and increase the score.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. Is there anyway around it?

Comment: To start with I would do Star class with two subclasses 3PS and 4PS. Second thing is, you forgot about using the else branch after if. You can test first if it 4PS then count the score accordingly, in the else clause you already know you have 3PS star so you count your score other way arround.